# Two HTML frames with same name and a form with target set to the frame name. How to bypass in Chrome to target the most inner frame?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, frame

In the below html page, it is having 2 frameset with similar frame names. It is also having a form “newform” which is having target = “A”. Now, in IE the form is targeting FRAME - PART 2, while in Chrome it is targeting FRAME - PART 1.
Now, as the form.target takes frameName in String, providing dynamic path for the frame fetches the same frame name, i.e., “A”. 
How to bypass the code in Chrome to point to FRAME - PART 2?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function test(){
        document.newform.target = “A”;
        document.newform.submit();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<frameset>
    <frame name=”A”></frame> //--------------PART 1
    <frame name=”B”></frame>
</frameset>
<iframe>
    <frameset>
        <frame name=”A”></frame>    //--------------PART 2
        <frame name=”B”></frame>
        <form name=”newform”></form>
    </frameset>
</iframe>
```

** When I mark the form target as "A", it refers to the first frame. My question is, how can I modify the below code to point the one in PART2.

document.newform.target = “A”;  //need to modify this part to point to PART 2

Comment: Why are you inserting a `<frameset>` inside an `<iframe>`? Pretty sure that's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can query for the property name to get all matches and then get the last one with:

```
framesA = document.querySelectorAll('[name="A"]');
frameA = framesA[framesA.length - 1]
```

but only if you are sure of the order in which they appear in the html.

I don't think you can get a consistent behavior only depending on html markup, as your issue is clearly caused by ambiguous syntax and you should primarily look to fix the cause.